# PHP - Mysql query problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to see if the logged in user is verified. But there is an error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/psmcouk/public_html/colemansystems/verify.php
>   on line 332

Here is the PHP code:

```
$user1 = $_SESSION['usr'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName=$user1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //LINE 332
  {
  $valid = $row['valid'];

  }
  if($valid == "1"){
      echo "$user1, you're account is currently verified.";

  }
```

I just can not see what is wrong with this code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the answers above are lame.

```
$user1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usr']);
$query = "SELECT valid FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName='$user1' and valid=1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
$valid = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($valid){
  echo "$user1, your account is currently verified.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked first time! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an SQL error. Try

```
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName='$user1'") 
          or die(mysql_error()); // to get if any error exists
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess $user should be quoted:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName='$user1'");
```

You can always see whats wrong my placing echo `mysql_error();` after the query

Answer (score 1):

As already posted, you just have to put the user name in single quotations marks:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName = '".$user1."'";
```

Assuming, that the user name column is `varchar`. The code you used is only valid if you compare numbers, e.g. integers.

A general remark: Depending on the size of the columns of your database, it might be resonable to select specific rows rather than all using `*`. For instance:

```
$query = "SELCT memberName, valid FROM phpbb_members";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user1 = $_SESSION['usr'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName=$user1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_field($result)) //LINE 332
  {
  $valid = $row['valid'];

  }
  if($valid == "1"){
      echo "$user1, you're account is currently verified.";

  }
```

try this.

Answer (score -1):

You should test the result of mysql_query before using it, if you follow the examples from php.net :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_members WHERE memberName=$user1");
if (!$result) {
  die('Request problem : ' . msql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //LINE 332
...
```